# Checking if a BTC seed exists with Python

Tags: python

I want users to be able to put their seed in my application if they forgot their password, is there a library/way to check if the seed they provided is valid?

edit: for clarification it does not need to get the wallets actual data like balance, etc. just check if the seed is tied to a wallet so users can recover it

Comment: Hi interesting, perhaps passlib would be of interest https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: I'll look into that, thank you!